# É possível criar link para o arquivo anexo no próprio email?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tenho a seguinte rotina:

```
//Preparando o email

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'nome@exemplo.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Seu nome';
$email->Subject   = 'Assunto';
$email->Body      = 'Corpo do email';
$email->AddAddress( 'destinatario@exemplo.com' );

//Anexando o arquivo

$file1 = 'caminho/do/arquivo/para/anexo1.png';
$email->AddAttachment( $file1 , 'anexo1.png' );

$file2 = 'caminho/do/arquivo/para/anexo2.png';
$email->AddAttachment( $file2 , 'anexo2.png' );

//Enviando o email

$email->Send();
```

Pergunta:

É possível criar um link para apontar para um arquivo do próprio email?

exemplo:

```
$email->Body      = '<a href="anexo1.png"> arquivo1 </a> <a href="anexo2.png"> arquivo2 </a>';
```

Minha necessidade:

Tenho que enviar uma lista de QRCodes para o cliente e gostaria que ele pudesse abrir cada um deles individualmente para não ter problema na leitura, os arquivos serão enviados para o email porque uma vez baixado ele poderá usar mesmo sem internet, por isso não posso tem um link que o leve para um servidor externo ao email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Sintaxe dos links para recursos "embutidos" no email:

O "URL" de um recurso anexo/embedded de email é definido por este header:

```
Content-Id: <anexo1.png@site.com>
```

O header deve ser posto dentro "parte" do próprio anexo (cada parte de uma mensagem mime/multipart tem seus headers específicos). Por exemplo, se tiver 3 anexos que necessitem do link, pode por um cabeçalho Content-Id com um valor diferente em cada uma das "partes".

Aí no corpo do email esse recurso é linkado com este formato:

```
<img src="cid:anexo1.png@site.com">
```

No exemplo acima usei o mesmo nome da imagem antes da `@`, mas poderia ser outra string arbitrária, desde que única, e respeite a respectiva RFC (todo: por o numero aqui), obviamente.

Nota que a `@` está na RFC, e o fato de por `site.com` não significa que o recurso acessará o servidor. O usual é por um domínio relativo ao serviço por questão de organização apenas.

Isso vale para outros tipos de anexo, obviamente que se for um PDF vai usar um `<link>` em vez de `<img>`, mas os princípios são os mesmos.

#### Usando PHPMailer:

Com PHPMailer o caminho mais simples para já acrescentar o Header automaticamente é trocar

```
$email->AddAttachment( $file1 , 'anexo1.png' );
```

por

```
$email->AddEmbeddedImage($file1, 'anexo1.png@site.com');
```

Neste caso, o segundo parâmetro é o `$cid`, que é o Content-Id da imagem já explicado.

Note que apesar de o `AddEmbeddedImage` ser uma função específica do PHPMailer, você pode fazer isso com qualquer linguagem ou editor, basta colocar o Header `Content-Id` nos headers do anexo específico, seja ele um PDF ou qualquer coisa (e isso independe de ser inline ou não o recurso).

Comment: Quando um e-mail tem vários anexos, como fica o header `Content-Id`?

Comment: @CypherPotato o header é no anexo a ser linkado. Pode por um em cada anexo, desde que não seja a mesma string.